How to schedule SQL stored procedure of a Snowflake linked server
I have a snowflake DB that I want to copy into a SQL Server database.
The .NET connector in C# is too slow to work with so I thought about schedule a stored procedure that will copy a part of the database of the Snowflake to a SQL Server, and use SQL Server for the main database.
I successfully linked the SnowFlake server. I create a very simple stored procedure:
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[Test]
AS
    INSERT INTO [Test].[dbo].[ID] (id_number)
        SELECT ID 
        FROM [SNOWFLAKE].[GEAR].[INSIGHTS].[APP_USERS] 
        WHERE FIRST_NAME = 'DAVID'

The stored procedure work great when I call it:
EXEC Test

Now I tried to schedule this stored procedure and I'm getting this error:
SELECT * FROM OPENQUERY([SNOWFLAKE], 
'SELECT * From [SNOWFLAKE].[GEAR].[INSIGHTS].[MFG_DM_APP_USERS]')


Executed as user: NT SERVICE\SQLSERVERAGENT. Cannot initialize the data source object of OLE DB provider "MSDASQL" for linked server "SNOWFLAKE". [SQLSTATE 42000] (Error 7303)  OLE DB provider "MSDASQL" for linked server "SNOWFLAKE" returned message "[Snowflake][Snowflake] (38)
Failed to authenticate a user by external browser: 31.     ". [SQLSTATE 01000] (Error 7412).  The step failed.

I can't understand what the difference is between execute the stored procedure by myself and by scheduling.
Thank you for your help.

The error is clear, the service account doesn't have permissions, you do.

i understand that, but why the stored procedure is working when i execute it manually? and not in scheduling?

As I said it's a different account, your account and the service account - which naturally has minimal permissions. The error tells you that also.

Ok, so how can i fix this? Thank you

Grant your service account the required permissions

I added to the linked server the User of: NT SERVICE\SQLSERVERAGENT
i also changed all the permission of: NT SERVICE\SQLSERVERAGENT granted every possible permission but i'm still getting the same error

If you are using the local server account then granting NT SERVICE\SQLSERVERAGENT  on the remote host isn't going to help. You'll need the job to run under different credentials, have agent run under a domain account (that has all the access in needs in both locations), or grant the host the SQL Server is running on access to the Snowflake instance (if Snowflae supports Machine permissions, I don't know).

@ThomA - Thank you for your answer, you are right but how can achieve that? first time i'm using linked server.
i granted to NT SERVICE\SQLSERVERAGENT all the permission (in the login) but it's not working.
The stored procedure itself is working but not in the SQL Agent.
in the SQL Agent i change also the user by 'sa' but same issue.

Perhaps having Agent run as a domain account, which has all the correct permissions in both environments, will be best then. HOw to set that up, however, isn't a question for [so], as it's not programming related.
